# When updating root index.html how to show users that site is on maintenance now?

Tags: site-maintenance

I'm working on a project. I can upload a site files to the web server.

I have a site which is running. I want to update my site but I know visitors are coming 24 hours a day. So, how could I update my site without losing visitors?

When I visit big websites under maintenance, in general, I see some another page. I just want to do the same for my website.

**Question Improved:**

I want to update a whole site not only `index.html`, should I rename the `index.html` file to another name to not users come in the website or there is another solution without renaming the file.

I also dont have much idea about *.htaccess* file all I know is that it is used to redirect domains but I dont know how and what can I do to *.htaccess* so I dont have rename the `index.html` file.

Comment: Can you improve your question? It's hard to understand the current phrasing?

Comment: Are you literally updating just "index.html" or the entire framework of your website?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to notify your users that your site is under maintenance, you can temporarily redirect all your pages to a maintenance page with an *.htaccess* file (if you use Apache as a web server). To do this, add these lines in your *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000 # no redirect for your IP
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Instead of a redirect, you could also consider sending a 503 and a `Retry-After` header... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55659/1243

Comment: @w3d: good point, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

How about displaying a message in your **main page** with something like:

> We are currently upgrading this website to serve your better. During this process you may continue browse our website using links below. Please let us know if your encounter any problem...