# What is best practice for search engines when a website is under maintenance?

Tags: seo, http-headers, 302-redirect, http-code-503

I need around a week to transition a heavily data-driven website from one back end to another. During that time I do plan to attempt to keep some pages live, but they won't all work well or look brilliant. Some pages won't work at all.

What is the best way to ensure I don't scare Google? Should I hide everything from robots.txt, or mark everything that doesn't work as "503", or are there other things that I should be considering?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When updating root index.html how to show users that site is on maintenance now?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58000/when-updating-root-index-html-how-to-show-users-that-site-is-on-maintenance-now)

Comment: or this one... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/how-to-set-restrictions-on-my-website/55659#55659

Comment: @Zistoloen Not a duplicate for that; though the answer is similar, I notice. I have no interest in just changing one page.

Comment: @w3d That is, indeed, a great answer to a similar issue - though hardly findable with the question the OP asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

503 everything is the best strategy I can think of, together with a retry after HTTP header.

Source: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html

Comment: Great answer, thank you: great to see that Google have already thought of this one. I hadn't considered the "retry-after".

Comment: Thanks. I would also consider a custom 503 error page. You don't want to scare off your visitors with the ugly default message. Analytics code on this page is also recommended.