# Website maintenance - SEO - 503

Tags: site-maintenance, http-code-503

I've to do some big works to my website, so I've to put it offline for some hours, but I don't want to lose my rank in google. I've read this tutorial: http://www.branded3.com/blogs/handle-googlebot-during-site-downtime/ This is the correct procedure, right?

I've also another question. Where should I put this code?

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
header("Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
header("Retry-After: 3600");
php?>
```

In the index.php, ora in a new page named errorpage.php in the root? Google will find this automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the `Status` header - that's non-standard and unnecessary IMO. See also these other questions: [How do I temporarily disable a website?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61241/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-a-website/61242) and [How to set restrictions on my website?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/how-to-set-restrictions-on-my-website/55659)

Comment: @w3d +1 for the links (I think this one is a duplicate), but the `Status` header is [required for fastcgi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Do you mean that I can remove this line? `header("Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");` I'm sorry but I really don't have idea about how these things work.

Comment: @Yogu Thanks for the info regarding the `Status` header and FastCGI. However, I think if PHP is configured properly then this should be unnecessary (PHP should convert it as reqd)? See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828275/still-necessary-to-use-status-404-not-found-for-fcgi

Comment: @daimpa: In theory, yes. However, as Yogu mentioned, this can depend on your server. Both the `HTTP/1.1...` and `Status:` lines do the same thing but in different server environments. Ideally, you should only need the first one (and PHP should convert it as reqd). (You should still use the `Retry-After` header.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application. If your application has a front controller like WordPress, then you can use `index.php` to make the complete site offline, since all requests go via `index.php`.

If your application consists of individual PHP files, then you have to put the code to each file.

Comment: If you have a collection of files (the 2nd part of this answer), you can use a .htaccess to rewrite all pages to your temp-unavailable.php

Comment: So, if I put this on my .htaccess in the root, I've done everything correctly?
`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*google.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* /errorpage.php`