# Redirecting all traffic to an HTML landing page

Tags: seo, redirects, landing-page

We are currently redirecting all website traffic to a static html page using javascript in the header of each page (the site will be like this for 4 days).

I'm concerned about the potential SEO impact.

The static HTML page currently has index 'no follow' and the other pages do still exist. It is just that the javascript when someone reaches those other pages sends them to the landing page via the below method.

**Here's the script:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
    window.location = "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/landing-page.html"
   //-->
</script>
```

Can anyone advise best practice in terms of this redirect?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: We have a store promotion - and the website is temporarily closed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the page is issuing a 302 header code. This indicates a temporary redirect and shouldn't adversely impact rankings if it's temporary. An alternative is a 503 maintenance code which does not impact Google ranks if it's temporary.

Keep in mind that Google will legitimately assume the content being searched for can't be found and begin demoting if it can't find it. You should recover once the redirect is lifted. Check your Webmaster to monitor scrapes and codes being received by Google.

Comment: Since the "website is temporarily closed" I think my preference would be for a 503 Service Unavailable with a `Retry-After` HTTP response header (in which you can state "4 days"). See also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/website-is-under-maintenance-how-to-restrict-access/55659#55659