# Webshop closed on Sunday, HTTP 503?

Tags: seo, http-code-503

One of my customers wants his webshop to be closed at Sundays. We've made a page that will be shown on Sunday, but what is the best practice concerning SEO?

- Return HTTP-status 503 (with a 'Retry-After' header, to tell bot/crawler to come back at Monday 0:00) and display Sunday page
- Redirect with Javascript (window.location.href) and disallow Sunday page in robots.txt
- Any other suggestions?

(Of course Javascript is less 'reliable' than a server side redirect, but this is just about SEO)

Comment: Although your question may not be related to religious reasons, [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90967/say-a-customer-is-an-observant-jew-and-wants-his-site-to-be-offline-on-shabat) related question might help.

Comment: Does "closed" mean that users simply can't buy anything, but can still "browse" or that the site is completely inaccessible at this time?

Comment: Thanks @dan, same issue for my customer.


"Closed" means that all pages are redirected to the 'Sunday page', so every page is redirected/inaccessible except the Sunday page.